# Can't get port.emit and port.on to work in a Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am sending a message like this:

```
self.port.emit("nodes_grubed", textNodesValues);
```

And want to react to it:

```
worker.port.on("nodes_grubed", requestRenderedtext);
```

But it doesn't work. What should I change? You can try my add-on [here](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1051796/latest/).

`main.js`:

```
var widgets = require("widget");
var tabs = require("tabs");
var self = require("self");

function requestRenderedtext(textNodesText) {
  console.log('text nodes requesting');
} 

var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Mozilla website",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: 
    function(worker) {
      tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: self.data.url("process.js")
      });
      worker.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
      worker.port.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
    },
  onAttach:
    function(worker) {
      worker.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
      worker.port.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
    }
});
widget.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
widget.port.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext);
```

`process.js`:

```
function getTextNodes() {
  var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body, 
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
    null, 
    false
  );

  var node;
  textNodes = [];
  var textNodesValues=[];
  while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
    if (node.parentNode.tagName!='SCRIPT') {
      textNodesValues.push(node.nodeValue);
      textNodes.push(node)   
    }
  }
  if (textNodesValues.length!=0) {
    console.log('emmiting nodes');
    self.port.emit("nodes_grubed", textNodesValues);
  }
}

getTextNodes();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the worker as a parameter when your widget is clicked (it doesn't exist when the click happens) - you create it by calling `tabs.activeTab.attach()`. You should use the return value of `tabs.activeTab.attach()`, like this:

```js
  onClick: 
    function() {
      var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: self.data.url("process.js")
      });
      worker.port.on("nodes_grubed", requestRenderedtext);
    },
```

Comment: second, ill try...
but why widget.port.on("nodes_grubed",requestRenderedtext) don't work?

Comment: @user1383846: Because your content script runs in the tab, not in the widget. Listening for a message from the widget is pretty pointless then. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask